# React-Spring app throws "export 'useSpring' (imported as 'useSpring') was not found in 'react-spring'"

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-spring

I started to study React-Spring. But I can't solve one problem.

1. I used npm install react-spring.
2. then, I copied most simple code in react-spring homepage.

```
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring'

function App() {

  const props = useSpring({ to: { opacity: 1 }, from: { opacity: 0 } })
  
return <animated.div style={props}>I will fade in</animated.div>

}
```

3. This error occurs.

> export 'useSpring' (imported as 'useSpring') was not found in 'react-spring' (possible exports: a, animated)

Comment: Please check the version of react-spring you are using. Here is a link to working sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-morning-8z2y3d?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Seems no issues in your code. Pls, recheck that your spring is installed at the root of your app. Hope it would work.